# why does my output show (False, "only", 1, "left") i wanted it without brakets, commas and quotation

Tags: python

When I write

```
vote_count = 99
target = vote_count == 100, "only", 100 - vote_count, "left"
print(target)
```

the output shows

```
(False, 'only', 1, 'left')
```

my expectation was

```
False only 1 left
```

I tried everything, but it just wouldn't want to work

Comment: Your expectation was wrong; that's not how `tuple.__str__` works. You need to write your own function to produce the string you want from a tuple.

Comment: Try `print(*target)`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the target as args to print.

`print(*target)`